# js, react: cannot reenable a button that is rendered as disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a simple buttoN.

```
            <Button id='button1' disabled onClick={() => buttonClick(false)}variant="contained">Text</Button>
```

This button is rendered as a grayed out version of itself, which is good.

Now, I want to enable the button. It should be:

```
document.getElementById("button1").disabled = false;
```

But nothing is enabled again.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Have the disabled value as part of your component state. Any re-render is going to reset the disabled value.

Comment: the original value is disabled. if that is what u mean

Comment: No, I mean, use `useState` or the class equivalent if you're still using class-based Components.

Comment: give me a code example please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should avoid using `document.getElementById` and similar in React whenever possible.
To make your button enable, do the following:

```
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);

return (
    <>
        <Button id='button1' disabled={isDisabled} onClick={() => buttonClick(false)}variant="contained">Text</Button>
        <div onClick={() => setIsDisabled(value => !value)}>toggle disabled</div>
    </>
)
```

Comment: please consider marking my answer as correct if you consider it worthy to do so :)

Comment: sorry, i couldnt do it right away. i did it now :)